# How to deal with images that have white spots because of lighting while making snapshot?

Tags: language-agnostic, image-processing

Does anyone know how to remove the effect of the bright white spots on the image?
That is, these spots occur because of the lighting when photographing. As a result, these spots affect the further processing of the image.
If you cut a white spot of light from the image, then the results will be very good.
This happens if you make a picture at dark place, and because of the camera's flash the resulting image contains white spot. The whole image is dark, but with bright white spot.
If you binarize that image the result is bad too. And histogram equalization doesn't help.

It is a program, it must deal with that images with white spot. So I need some algorithm of solving that problem automatically.

Comment: Remove in what context/program/language/API/method/... ?

Comment: I need an algorithm (method) to remove that effect. The program will use it.

Comment: are your images constrained such that the white spots always appear in the same location in your image?

Comment: yep!
but what if another spot will be there because of light coming from some place? I mean more complex case.
But initially yes the spot is at the same place always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some work done at MIT on compensating for poor lighting in photographs.  I don't know if it is up to the task of a very bright flash, but from my reading of the paper it seems like it ought to be (provided there was only one other major source of light when the photo was taken).  Certainly the results in the paper look very impressive.  You will find more info, including many sample imaages, at  http://people.csail.mit.edu/ehsu/work/sig08lme.